# Pygame: Why Won't My Player Animation Play?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Hello I am currently working on a survival shooter game and I am currently getting frustrated at a few things. One being my player animation not working. I have the code for the player class right here:

```
import pygame
from zombie import *

# Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, gravity):

        # Player dimensions and position

        # Player image and animation
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/Sprites/player.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/Sprites/player2.png'))
        #~ self.images.append(pygame.image.load('ball1.png'))
        #~ self.images.append(pygame.image.load('ball2.png'))
        self.maxImage = len(self.images)
        self.currentImage = 0

        #~ self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 80, 80)
        self.rect = self.images[0].get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.timeTarget = 10
        self.timeNum = 1

        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0

        self.health = 100

        # Jump and gravity
        self.jumping = False
        self.on_ground = False
        self.origJumpVel = 15
        self.jumpVel = self.origJumpVel
        self.gravity = 0.5

    # Jump inputs
    def do_jump(self):
        if self.jumping and not self.on_ground:
            self.velY = -self.jumpVel
            self.jumpVel -= self.gravity

        if self.on_ground:
            self.jumping = False
            self.jumpVel = self.origJumpVel
            self.velY = 0
            self.on_ground = True

    def handle_events(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if not self.jumping:
                    self.jumping = True
                    self.on_ground = False

            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                self.velX = -5

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                self.velX = +5

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                self.velX = 0

    # PLayer updates
    def update(self):
        # Animations
        if self.timeNum == self.timeTarget:
            self.currentImage += 1
            if self.currentImage >= self.maxImage:
                self.currentImage = 0
            self.timeNum = 1

        # Health
        #if self.rect.x == zombie.rect.x:
            #self.health -= 10

        # Screen wrap
        if self.rect.right > 1280:
            self.rect.left = 0

        elif self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.right = 1280

    # Player rendering
    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.images[self.currentImage], self.rect)
```

If you want to know about any of my other problems/frustrations just say so. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: We can't do anything with the code you've posted.  You don't have any sort of game loop shown, and I don't see anything that is modifying the value of `timeTarget`.  Since I can't see where that is happening, I can't tell why your animation code in the `update` function might not be working.

Comment: Do you want the main game loop too then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
if self.timeNum == self.timeTarget:
    # ...
    self.timeNum += 1
```

but `self.timeNum` is 1 and `self.timeTarget` is 10 so it can't be run and it can't change `self.timeNum`

You probably need

```
if self.timeNum == self.timeTarget:
    # ...
    # inside of `if`
    self.timeNum = 0

# outside of `if`
self.timeNum += 1
```